# Randomly select an array from group of "enabled" arrays

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a set of four arrays. I also have an option to either enable or disable 3 of the 4 arrays (one is always enabled).

Is there a way to randomly decide which array to pull a value from (of the arrays indicated as enabled)?

I originally was aiming to make a master array and just append the content of the other enabled ones into it, but it proved a little harder than expected. I figured it would be easier to simply randomly select an array to pull the single value from as long as it was "enabled".

I'm currently pulling the value with a simple statement such as

```
If ????? {
    return promptArrayA[desiredIndexA]

} else if { ?????
    return promptArrayB[desiredIndexB]

} else if { ?????
    return promptArrayC[desiredIndexC]

} else { 
    return promptArrayD[desiredIndexD]
```

I'm thinking if I had a "randomizer" that chose one of the enabled arrays, then I can use that as a constraint in an If Statement.

I'm fairly new to Swift so any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array randomly by doing:

```
let enabledArrays = [promptArrayA, promptArrayB, promptArrayC, promptArrayD]
let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<enabledArrays.count)
let randomArray = enabledArrays[randomIndex]
return randomArray[desiredIndex]
```

Comment: Why not `enabledArrays.randomElement()` or `enabledArrays[.random(in: enabledArrays.indices)]`?

Comment: That would work as well, I didn't know if he wanted to use the `randomIndex` to know which array got picked or to then pick one of the desiredIndexes since he had different ones in the question

Comment: @JoseCastellanos, whenever I try this, the build fails and says the following error
"cannot use instance member 'aList' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"
Any idea how to fix this?